# how to set a row of Swing Jtable to 'selected'?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I managed to search but did not get the answer I wanted. Please allow me writing here.

Let's say I have a Swing JTable, each row has an ID (also other data). I know I can find out the row with a given ID, by implementing a function in tableModel. My question is, if I have an ID, how can I set the row to 'selected' status in JTable? it should be equivalent to 'using mouse to single click on that row'.

It looks there is not a method like 'setRowToSelected(int rowIndex)' in JTable?

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of another question. The solution in the other posting was to use `table.setRowSelectionInterval(...)`. Yes, this does set the row selection, but it does not change the cell that has focus (which is what happens when you click on a cell).

Answer (score 7):

> it should be equivalent to 'using mouse to single click on that row'.

```
table.changeSelection(...);
```

This will cause the row to be selected and the cell selection to change.

The other option that was pointed to in another thread was:

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(...);
```

This will just select the row, but the current cell selection will remain.